# Overpainting corner hutch

Tags: furniture, refinishing, paint

I would like to refinish the inside of a corner hutch. Below are images of the current condition.

[image]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

[image]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

The current plan is to paint the inside of the hutch the same color. I plan to clean the inside of the hutch with some rubbing alcohol or something similar. Also I plan to sand the inside with 220 grit sanding paper. The current thought is use an acrylic paint to paint the inside.

**Questions**:

- Should I use a different sanding paper grit?
- Is there an alternative to rubbing alcohol?

---

**References:**

- [China Cabinet Makeover](https://www.jennaburger.com/2014/09/how-to-prep-and-sand-wood-furniture/)
- [How to Update a Black Lacquer Hutch](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/update-black-lacquer-hutch-57988.html)

Comment: Not so much _refinishing_ in the woodworking sense. You might want to check DIY to see how others would do this. Bear in mind it really has to do with what the current finish happens to be. If it is an oil-based paint the surface prep will be different than if it isn't.

Comment: @jdv, How do I figure out is an oil based paint or not. What are the other types that I should consider. Is Lacquers a paint type that is used on wood.

Comment: That would be best as a separate question. I'm surprised that this question wasn't already on DIY.SE. I t might be asking there, as I'm sure many there know the "rub the paint with a swab dipped in denatured alcohol" trick. If the swab stays clean, it's oil-based. If  some paints comes off, it is probably a water emulsion style paint.

Comment: Definitely check the previous Q&A here and on DIY.SE. There are lots of "how to repaint over paint" Q&A on DIY.

Comment: It may be easier and less time consuming to paint it with a good bonding primer and then any paint you like after that.

Comment: @jdv, Thank you for the feedback

Comment: @AlaskaMan thank you for the feedback

Comment: You might consider scraping the paint off of those dings in the shelf edges and filling them in with some wood putty. Sand the putty smooth, then sand back the paint to make a nice, smooth, feathered edge from the existing paint level back to the bare wood level so you don't have a ridge showing through the finished paint.

Answer (score 2):

Your plan is sound. You must sand to scuff up any/all sheen on the existing paint. 220 is suitable (... I almost said *fine*) or you could start coarser and sand again with 220 to remove fine scratches. No primer is necessary if you sand like described.

No alcohol wipe is necessary; in fact it could cause problems if it softens or wrinkles the existing paint. Just wipe down well with damp cloth. Acrylic paint will work fine over existing alkyd (oil-base) or water base as long as the sanding regimen is followed.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb with overpainting (or over-finishing, since this applies to clear finishes also) is that as long as the surface is completely clean, dull (matt) and dust-free you should get a decent bond<sup>1</sup>.

> Should I use a different sanding paper grit?

220 is a good choice. You could go a little coarser<sup>2</sup> or a little finer and still get acceptable results, but 220 is a good mid-range grit for this type of job.

> Is there an alternative to rubbing alcohol?

Yes, many.

Just simply cleaning with hot soapy water may be enough to clean a surface sufficient to start the prep for refinishing, but it depends on what it is/might be contaminated with.

Waxes aren't soluble in soapy water (even if the water is hot) so a solvent of some kind would be needed if any furniture polish or other product containing wax was ever used over the existing paint. Mineral spirits (UK: white spirit, Oz: mineral turpentine) is a good choice for this purpose, plus is also ideal for removing greasy or oily residues without the minor risk of exposing the piece to water. And generally speaking no fully-cured paint is adversely affected by mineral spirits.

---

<sup>1</sup> This **does** also apply to polyurethane, putting the lie to the conventional wisdom that you can't overcoat stuff originally finished in poly.

<sup>2</sup> When painting you can sand more coarsely than when using a clear finish without it being a problem.